# Accessing control from a different function in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a hopefully simple question, for which I could not google up any solution:
I would like to add labels buttons textboxes at runtime, which i can in the constructor of my Form, but I cannot access them outside of the constructor.

Something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Label changeMe = new Label();
        changeMe.AutoSize = true;
        changeMe.Left = 50; changeMe.Top = 50;
        changeMe.Text = "Change this text from other function";
        changeMe.IsAccessible = true;

        //changeMe.Name = "changeMe";

        this.Controls.Add(changeMe);
    }

    private void btn_changeLabelText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Would like to achieve this:
        //changeMe.Text = "You changed me !! ";

        //But I found only this solution:
        //Label l;   l = (Label)this.Controls.Find("changeMe", true)[0];   l.Text = "You changed Me";

    }
}
```

The solution I commented out is the only one I found, but I can't believe there isn't any better one then that. Is there a way to make my controls public for example? Whats a good way of solving this problem?

(The number of controls vary on every time I call my Dialogbox I am trying to design)

Thanks

EDIT --------------------------

After accepting Adil's answer, I stayed with the following solution, which I only find better as the originally outcommented this.Control.Find way, because I also want to have "n" Textboxes, and in thie way I can easily loop through them and read inputs.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public struct labels { public Label lbl; public int id; }
    List<labels> lbls = new List<labels>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Label changeMe = new Label();
        changeMe.AutoSize = true;
        changeMe.Left = 50; changeMe.Top = 50;
        changeMe.Text = "Change this text from other function";
        changeMe.IsAccessible = true;


        this.Controls.Add(changeMe);
        labels newlabel = new labels();
        newlabel.id = 137; newlabel.lbl = changeMe;
        lbls.Add(newlabel);

    }

    private void btn_changeLabelText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbls.Find(i => i.id == 137).lbl.Text = "You changed me";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared the label inside constructor that makes it accessible only in constructor, ceclare `label` out side constructor at `class scope` as class member.

```
Label changeMe = new Label();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Label changeMe = new Label();
    changeMe.AutoSize = true;
    changeMe.Left = 50; changeMe.Top = 50;
    changeMe.Text = "Change this text from other function";
    changeMe.IsAccessible = true;

    //changeMe.Name = "changeMe";

    this.Controls.Add(changeMe);
}
```

Comment: What if I have to make n labels? If I am not mistaken I can only give n as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: You can declare array of labels and initialize them using for loop, this could be helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962449/array-of-labels

Comment: This post states how to use loop to create labels, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170673/how-can-i-create-labels-inside-a-for-loop

Comment: I have a code now, that is running, based on your answer regarding the scope. However I am not sure, setting up lists and arrays for this does not seem more elegant to me, then the this.control.find version which I commented out, where I can also define an ID, as control.name. Is there really no other way? If you say so, I am accepting your answer

Comment: You can use loop variable to make unique names for all labels like changeMe.Name = "changeMe" + i.ToString(); and it will be unique identifier for each label.

Comment: Thanks for your help, accepted as solution, and updated my post with the way I implemented it.