# Unable to debug website project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I have been bashing my head against this all morning without success. I have inherited a project from long gone developers and there is now, what I thought would be, a minor change to some code.

Every time I add a breakpoint I get the message shown below. The censor blocks are just hiding our customer's name.

[image]

I have attempted multiple times to rebuild the project but I still get the same issue that the server runs to old version of the code.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899428/break-point-is-not-hitting-while-debugging) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059051/breakpoints-in-code-behind-not-hit) but they have not helped.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you make sure the server has the latest version of the code?

Comment: @mason the code I have is the same as the live version. I grabbed this code direct off the server via FTP as this project was not previously in source control.

Comment: Did you try following the directions in the error message?

Comment: Yes I did and I still can't hit the breakpoint.

Comment: @Burgi, do you mean that you have enabled the option: uncheck "Require source files to exactly match the original version" and "Enable Just My Code" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging? If one file is different from the one which was compiled into the executable during debugging, can you find and reference the matched version file? It seems that it was related to the specific .cs file, can you remove and re-add the correct version again?

Comment: @Burgi， any updates?

Comment: @JackZhai I have ensured that those options are unticked and ticked respectively and I don't get the warning any more but the breakpoints still aren't hit.

Comment: @Burgi， put the mouse on the breakpoint which was not hit in debugging time, do you get any other warning messages? Do you enable the symbols server under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols?

Comment: I have enabled the symbols but there is no change

Comment: @Burgi, do you get any messages? Please also view the output windows during debugging time.